# Form Submit appends URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

i want to submit an form using Jquery.But my form Url appends with existing URL and submitting the form with the appended URL.

Before Submit :

URL on Browser : `localhost:8000/view/items`

HTML:

```
     <form action="edit/items" method="post" id="editform">
            <input type="hidden" id="itemID" value="blahblah">
            <a href="#" id="editItem">Edit</a>
        </form>
```

JQuery:

```
$("#editProperty").click(function(e){
    $("#editPropertyForm").submit();
});
```

After Form Submit I get i.e URL goes as : `localhost:8000/view/items/edit/items`

How do i solve it ?

Comment: Your action is a relative URL, which means it must append to the current URL.  Put a forward slash before the `edit`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your form's action is a relative path. I think what you want is `"/edit/items"`. That'll take the root path and add edit/items to it.

Comment: Whoo !! Yes .. Thanks Worked . Sorry am so Stupid :(

Comment: It's not stupid, it's just a typo, happens all the time.

Comment: if i have to redirect it to www.google.com, then what should be the parameter.

Answer (score 5):

Change your form action from a relative to an absolute URL, i.e.:

```
<form action="/edit/items" method="post" id="editform">
```